# How do I reference a variable in a different sub in ms-access VBA?

Tags: sql, database, vba, ms-access

What I have is a separate Private Sub that gets a value and sets it as variable "Record" with type Double.

Now I need to be able to reference that value even though it is in another sub?

For example:

```
Private Sub GetValue()

Dim Record as Double

Record = (Code to find Record)

End Sub
```

How do I reference that "Record" in another Sub?

Thanks in advance,
Bob P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is you cant. Its private to that sub

What you need to do is either, have the

```
Dim Record as Double
```

in the general code, or, turn it into a function and return it so you can do

```
Myrecord = GetValue()
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm more a SQL Server and Excel guy, buy if I had to solve your problem, I'd do it in one of two ways.  That can't really be the body of your function, is it - because the Record is set as local, and then.... disappears!

1. Use a global variable. Just put the `Dim Record as Double` outside of any sub. This also means that it get set whenever you last call this Sub, assuming all other code only read from it.
2. Use a `Function` instead. Example below

---

```
Private Function GetRecord() as Double
    Dim Record as Double
    Record = ....
    GetRecord = Record
End Function
```